# multi threaded file transfer with socket problem

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, sockets

what I want to make is the multi-client,server file transfer with socket.
it compiled well and seems realistic.
But Problem is, Code won't act properly and client don't send file to server folder.
I don't know what is the problem.
Can anybody see code and tell what is the problem?
it would be grateful if you change my code also.

client

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


#include <signal.h>


#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <netdb.h>                      /* getprotobyname */
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>


// NOTE/BUG: this didn't provide enough space for a 5 digit port + EOS char
#if 0
enum { PORTSIZE = 5 };
#else
enum { PORTSIZE = 6 };
#endif


void
sig_handler(int signo)
{
    if (signo == SIGINT)
        printf("!!  OUCH,  CTRL - C received on client  !!\n");
}


int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct addrinfo hints,
    *res;
    char *server_hostname = "127.0.0.1";
    char file_path[BUFSIZ];
    char *server_reply = NULL;
    char *user_input = NULL;
    char buffer[BUFSIZ];
    int filefd;
    int sockfd;
    ssize_t read_return;
    struct hostent *hostent;
    unsigned short server_port = 12345;
    char portNum[PORTSIZE];
    char remote_file[BUFSIZ];
    int select;
    char *client_server_files[BUFSIZ];
    int i = 0;
    int j;
    char protoname[] = "tcp";
    struct protoent *protoent;
    struct sockaddr_in sockaddr_in;
    in_addr_t in_addr;



    // char filename_to_send[BUFSIZ];

    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage   ./client  <ip>  <port>\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    server_hostname = argv[1];
    server_port = strtol(argv[2], NULL, 10);


    /* Get socket. */
    protoent = getprotobyname(protoname);
    if (protoent == NULL) {
        perror("getprotobyname");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, protoent->p_proto);
    if (sockfd == -1) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    /* Prepare sockaddr_in. */
    hostent = gethostbyname(server_hostname);
    if (hostent == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: gethostbyname(\"%s\")\n", server_hostname);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    in_addr = inet_addr(inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr*)*(hostent->h_addr_list)));
    if (in_addr == (in_addr_t)-1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: inet_addr(\"%s\")\n", *(hostent->h_addr_list));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    sockaddr_in.sin_addr.s_addr = in_addr;
    sockaddr_in.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sockaddr_in.sin_port = htons(server_port);

    /* Do the actual connection. */
    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&sockaddr_in, sizeof(sockaddr_in)) == -1) {
        perror("connect");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    while (1) {
        if (signal(SIGINT, sig_handler)) {
            break;
        }

        puts("connected to the server");
        puts("-----------------");
        puts("|1 - listLocal| \n|2 - listServer| \n|3 - sendFile| \n|4 - help| \n|5 - exit| ");
        puts("-----------------");
        while (1) {
            printf("------%d",select);
            scanf("%d", &select);
            while ( getchar() != '\n' );



            switch (select) {
                case 1: // list files of client's directory
                    system("find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | sort");
                    sprintf(remote_file, "%s", "listLocal");
                    send(sockfd, remote_file, sizeof(remote_file), 0);
                    break;

                case 2: // listServer
                    sprintf(remote_file, "%s", "listServer");
                    send(sockfd, remote_file, sizeof(remote_file), 0);
                    puts("---- Files btw Server and the Client ----");
                    for (j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
                        puts(client_server_files[j]);
                    }
                    break;

                case 3: // send file
                    memset(file_path, 0, sizeof file_path);
                    scanf("%s", file_path);

                    sprintf(remote_file, "%s", "sendFile");
                    send(sockfd, remote_file, sizeof(remote_file), 0);

                    memset(remote_file, 0, sizeof remote_file);
                    // send file name to server
                    sprintf(remote_file, "%s", file_path);
                    send(sockfd, remote_file, sizeof(remote_file), 0);

                    filefd = open(file_path, O_RDONLY);
                    if (filefd == -1) {
                        perror("open send file");
                        //exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                        break;
                    }

                    while (1) {
                        read_return = read(filefd, buffer, BUFSIZ);
                        if (read_return == 0)
                            break;
                        if (read_return == -1) {
                            perror("read");
                            //exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                            break;
                        }
                        if (write(sockfd, buffer, read_return) == -1) {
                            perror("write");
                            //exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    // add files in char pointer array
                    client_server_files[i++] = file_path;

                    close(filefd);
                    break;

                case 5:
                    sprintf(remote_file, "%s", "exit");
                    send(sockfd, remote_file, sizeof(remote_file), 0);
                    free(user_input);
                    free(server_reply);
                    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

                default:
                    puts("Wrong selection!");
                    break;
            }


        }
    }

    free(user_input);
    free(server_reply);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

server

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>


#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <netdb.h>                      /* getprotobyname */
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>


#include <pthread.h>


struct client {
    socklen_t client_len;
    struct sockaddr_in client_address;
    int client_sockfd;
    pthread_t thread;
};




// NOTE: provide enough space for a 5 digit port + EOS char
enum { PORTSIZE = 6 };


double cpu_time_used;
clock_t start, end;




void *forClient(void *ptr);


void portCleaner(const char* port_num) {
    char temp[100] = "sudo lsof -t -i tcp:";
    sprintf(temp, "%s%s%s", temp, port_num, " | xargs kill -9;");
    system(temp);
    //puts(temp);
}


void
sig_handler(int signo)
{
    if (signo == SIGINT)
        printf("!!  OUCH,  CTRL - C received  by server !!\n");
}


int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct addrinfo hints,
    *res;
    int enable = 1;
    //int filefd;  // NOTE: this is never initialized/used
    int server_sockfd;
    unsigned short server_port = 12345u;
    char portNum[PORTSIZE];
    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    struct protoent *protoent;
    char protoname[] = "tcp";





#if 0
    int socket_index = 0;
#else
    struct client *ctl;
#endif

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage   ./server  <port>\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    server_port = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);

    /* Create a socket and listen to it.. */
    protoent = getprotobyname(protoname);
    if (protoent == NULL) {
        perror("getprotobyname");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    server_sockfd = socket(
                           AF_INET,
                           SOCK_STREAM,
                           protoent->p_proto
                           );
    if (server_sockfd == -1) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (setsockopt(server_sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &enable, sizeof(enable)) < 0) {
        perror("setsockopt(SO_REUSEADDR) failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    server_address.sin_port = htons(server_port);
    if (bind(
             server_sockfd,
             (struct sockaddr*)&server_address,
             sizeof(server_address)
             ) == -1
        ) {
        perror("bind");
        portCleaner(argv[1]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (listen(server_sockfd, 5) == -1) {
        perror("listen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "listening on port %d\n", server_port);



    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr,1);

    start = clock();

    while (1) {




        ctl = malloc(sizeof(struct client));
        if (ctl == NULL) {
            perror("malloc");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        ctl->client_len = sizeof(ctl->client_address);
        puts("waiting for client");

        ctl->client_sockfd = accept(server_sockfd,
                                    (struct sockaddr *) &ctl->client_address, &ctl->client_len);

        if (ctl->client_sockfd < 0) {
            perror("Cannot accept connection\n");
            close(server_sockfd);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }


        pthread_create(&ctl->thread, &attr, forClient, ctl);


    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


void *
forClient(void *ptr)
{

    end = clock();
    cpu_time_used = 1000 * (((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
#if 0
    int connect_socket = (int) ptr;
#else
    struct client *ctl = ptr;
    int connect_socket = ctl->client_sockfd;
#endif
    int filefd;
    ssize_t read_return;
    char buffer[BUFSIZ];
    char *file_path;
    char receiveFileName[BUFSIZ];
    char cmd[BUFSIZ];


    // Thread number means client's id
    printf("Connected time  [%lf] ---  Thread number [%ld]\n", cpu_time_used, pthread_self());




    // until stop receiving go on taking information
    while (recv(connect_socket, receiveFileName, sizeof(receiveFileName), 0)) {


        if((strcmp(receiveFileName, "listServer") == 0
           || strcmp(receiveFileName, "listLocal") == 0 || strcmp(receiveFileName, "help") == 0
            || strcmp(receiveFileName, "exit") == 0 || strcmp(receiveFileName, "sendFile") == 0)) {
            printf("--- Command <%s> ---\n", receiveFileName);
            continue;
        }

        file_path = receiveFileName;

        fprintf(stderr, "is the file name received? ?   =>  %s\n", file_path);

        filefd = open(file_path, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
        if (filefd == -1) {
            perror("open");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        do {
            read_return = read(connect_socket, buffer, BUFSIZ);
            if (read_return == -1) {
                perror("read");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            if (write(filefd, buffer, read_return) == -1) {
                perror("write");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        } while (read_return > 0);

        // NOTE/BUG: filefd was never closed
        close(filefd);

    }

    fprintf(stderr, "Client dropped connection\n");

    // NOTE: do all client related cleanup here
    // previously, the main thread was doing the close, which is why it had
    // to do the pthread_join
    close(connect_socket);
    free(ctl);

    return (void *) 0;
}
```

Comment: Your description of the problem is not helpful. What is the problem with the code? What questions do you have about that problem?

Comment: When I put the file path, the client should send file in to server's folder. but it sends nothing.

Comment: What i want is just send my client folder file to local server folder directory. in local server.

Comment: Maybe instead of doing this, look at an existing program/protocol that does this (like FTP) and understand that code, modifying it as needed. You are missing key basics needed to do something like this correctly. (In particular, you don't seem to understand what a byte stream is.)

Comment: Your edit which basically eliminated the text of the question is not considered acceptable so I rolled it back.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (recv(connect_socket, receiveFileName, sizeof(receiveFileName), 0)) {


    if((strcmp(receiveFileName, "listServer") == 0
```

You throw away the return value of `recv`, which is the only way to know how many bytes of data you received. So the rest of your code has no idea what data you actually received.

Then you pass the chunk of data you read to `strcmp`. But it's just a chunk of arbitrary data. It's not a string. You *cannot* pass something to `strcmp` unless it's a string.

You are missing a message protocol. Your client is supposed to send messages and your server needs to process messages. To do this, you need a message protocol that defines what a message is and then you need to write code to send and receive *messages*.

The `recv` function has no idea what your messages are and has no way to know where the message ends.

Since you're not experienced at using TCP, you should always start by specifying the protocol the server and client will use on top of TCP. If it's a message protocol, define specifically how messages will be represented on the wire. It may be helpful to look at the specifications for existing protocols layered on top of TCP such as SMTP or HTTP.

Otherwise, use a library that provides functions to send and receive messages instead of trying to use TCP directly.

Comment: SO i should use another function? how to send file with TCP/IP easily? I think multi client works,but file sending has an error.

Comment: @masterbeard7 Have a look at the specification for FTP, a protocol for sending files over TCP/IP. You need a protocol of some kind and winging it won't work. (You can also look at the specification for HTTP 0.9, the simplest version of that protocol.)

Comment: thanks , i will check it more. by then, it is nice to meet you!

Comment: I have ripple and I know your team. thanks for advice